# Speeding up Java clock (override how Date class/System.getCurrentTimeInMillis works)

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

We have an existing product that is very time sensitive.  For example, statistics are published on a 5 min, 1 hour, 24 hour basis.  This means testing is very slow in real world conditions (we actually don't test the 1 hour and 24 hour statistics because of this).

What I want is to speed up the JVM clock.... I know I could create a dummy time class as I've seen others do.  But the code base is huge so this would be a lot of retrofit work + third party libs would still use the normal Date Class/System.getCurrentTimeInMillis...

What I'm really looking for is a way to override the Java time behavior (monkey patching in the ruby world).  I'm guessing it should be possible to use byte code manipulation to do this.  But I'm not sure where to start....  I can't find any libraries that do this or anyone who has solved this problem via byte code manipulation.

question 1:  is it possible to override the Date behavior?
question 2:  how would one do this?  Perhaps an example of overriding another core java class?

thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Modify the system time (disable ntpd if in use), Java time will reflect accordingly.

Comment: BUT: Note that this very behavior is why Java Strongly Recommends that code use the monotonic clock (System.nanoTime()) when determining durations. In general, code that is affected by resetting the system clock -- unless it's specifically intended to look at the current local time -- is vulnerable to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches. Modify the Date class itself, or modify all references to it.

The Date class is part of the standard library, so it's given a privileged status. The only way I can think of to modify it is to actually modify the system jar. You can either put your modified jar in the normal location or tell the JVM to look elsewhere. Note that this is not officially supported by Oracle and is only really feasible for personal use.

The other approach is to modify all your classes to reference a mocked version of the class. Even in a large codebase, you can do this with a simple script. If you only care about normal references you can do this either statically or dynamically (as classes are loaded).

If you're worried about accessing Date via reflection, doing it dynamically is the only option. Typically you would use a custom class loader with ASM to do bytecode rewriting. In order to capture reflection, you would have to mock out all the reflection classes and replace references to those too. This gets pretty tricky, especially when you consider the possibility of using reflection to access reflection to access Date, but it's possible.

Also, note that bytecode rewriting won't let you mess with the system classes because they use the hardcoded system classloader. So if another system class references Date, it will use the unmodified version.

I believe Java Agents can also be used to do bytecode rewriting without the need for a custom classloader, but I don't have experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8

[Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) includes a new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (but re-architected).

These new classes supplant the notoriously troublesome classes of java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

### Mock Clock

Amongst the new classes is the abstract class, [Clock](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html).

The designers had exactly your need in mind, a pluggable replacement for the system clock to create fake "mock" date-time values to facilitate testing. The Clock class is meant to be extended by you (or others) for whatever unnatural behavior you desire. Pass an instance of that altered clock to the other java.time.* classes. Those other classes will use your Clock as a source of date-time data rather than the computer/JVM's real clock.

## Joda-Time

Looks like Joda-Time may have something similar. Read this discussion about a "MillisProvider". Apparently referring to [`DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider.html).